# A typedef struct syntax

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef struct {
int Key_value;
Node *link;
}Node;
```

Is the above declaration valid? or should I use

```
typedef struct _node{
int Key_value;
_node *link;
}Node;
```

Comment: why don't you compile and see it your self...

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c?rq=1

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, please be specific about which on you're using. I would expect this to be about C.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not valid (as you would have noticed if you tried to compile it).

The `typedef` alias isn't introduced until the after the `typedef`, so you can't use it inside itself.

The second one isn't valid either (in C), `_node` is not a valid type name. You must use `struct _node` for the self-reference.

I tend to use pre-declaration and split it:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
  int Key_Value;
  Node *link;
};
```

Comment: In C.  In C++, `_node* link;` is valid.  (Of course, in C++, you wouldn't normally write it like this anyway.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Correct, I failed to notice the question was dual-tagged.

Comment: Also identifiers like `_node` with a leading underscore shouldn't be use in file scope.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you can actually give the same name to both the structure and the typedef:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int Key_value;
    struct Node *link;
} Node;
```

Here I have added something which would have caused your code to not compile in a C compiler: The `typedef` isn't created until *after* the structure is defined. This means we must use the structure name in the `link` member declaration.

This can either be solved by giving the structure a name, as above, or by declaring the `typedef` first:

```
typedef struct Node *Node;

struct Node {
    int Key_value;
    Node *link;
};
```

---

Also note that in C++ you don't need to use the `typedef` keyword, or the `struct` keyword when declaring the `link` member:

```
// C++ version
struct Node {
    int Key_value;
    Node *link;
};
```

Structure (and class) names can be used as types in C++.

Comment: you have a `*` too much in your `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

The first declaration is invalid, because `Node` is not known when you declare `link` as a structure member. The reason is that a declaration name is visible only after the declarator (simply put, that is after a comma, equal sign, or semi-colon). So, `typedef` being a declaration like any other, the name `Node` is only visible after the final semi-colon that ends the declaration statement.

Thus, you must use the second form (the first won't even compile). However, if you're on C, note that you should prepend the `struct` keyword to `_node`, like this:

```
typedef struct _node {
    int Key_value;
    struct _node *link;
} Node;
```

This is not necessary if you're on C++.

Answer (score 0):

Both are invalid. Here's one valid way, for C and C++:

```
struct Node
{
    int Key_value;
    struct Node *link;
};


// if C, you can also do this
typedef struct Node Node;
```

The main point is that whatever the type of `Link` is, it must be something that's already been *declared*.  The line `struct X { ....` declares that `struct X` is a type (but does not define it yet, but that's OK).

Answer (score 0):

In C you should do:

```
typedef struct _node {
    int Key_value;
    struct _node *link;
} Node;
```

However, if you are using C++, it's simpler to omit the `typedef` at all:

```
struct Node {
    int Key_Value;
    Node* link;
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. An "addition" to other answers should come in form of a comment.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves you are right, answer edited to include C code